# How to query this table to find player who scored most amount of goals?

Tags: mysql

How can I query this table `results` to find out which `player_id` has scored the most amount of goals in a particular `community_id`?

```
+----------------+-------------+-----+
| Field          | Type        | Key |
+----------------+-------------+-----+
| results_id     | int         | Pri |
| community_id   | int         |     |
| player1_id     | int         |     |
| player1_goals  | int         |     |
| player2_id     | int         |     |
| player2_goals  | int         |     |
+----------------+-------------+-----+
```

NOTE: a player can either be player1 or player2 so their goals have to be added up accordingly, i.e:

```
SELECT Player ID, count (*) Goals FROM results
(SELECT SUM (player1_goals) WHERE player1_id = 2 AND community_id = 5) 
(SELECT SUM (player2_goals) WHERE player2_id = 2 AND community_id = 5) AS player_id GROUP BY Player ID ORDER BY Goals DESC
```

But I know that syntax is terribly incorrect...

My desired output is:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| Player ID   | Goals     |
+-------------+-----------+
| 14          | 64        |
| 8           | 43        |
| 7           | 17        |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregation *after* combining the tables:

```
select player, sum(goals)
from ((select player1_id as player, player1_goals as goals
       from results
       where community_id = 5
      ) union all
      (select player2_id as player, player2_goals as goals
       from results
       where community_id = 5
      )
     ) p
group by player
order by sum(goals) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: This works apart from line 1 needs to be select player, sum (goals)